# Python print like function for converting *args to a string

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I would like to know how to convert an unknown number of arguments to a string. what I need to do is redirect the output of a function that is supposed to go to print() to a Qt QPlainTextEdit. since it only accepts strings, I need a way to convert the given arguments to a string.

basically what I am looking for is print() but instead of outputting to the terminal, the output is to a string.

Comment: Use `self.console_log_ext("".join([str(e) for e in args]))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have an array of elements you can do:

```
def print_foo(arr,count):
    for i in range(0,int(count)):
        print(str(arr[i]))
```

Basically, converting to string is - `newstr = str(variable)`